# Issue generating proper JSON array response

Tags: php, json

**Essentially I have the following PHP script that generates a response based on output of the query, I need the JSON to in a different format with each response listed sequentially:**

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('

    SELECT
        `table1`.`id`, 
        `table1`.`option`
        FROM `table1`
        WHERE `table1`.`source` = 1
    ');

$stmt->execute([

]);

$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowcount = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($rowcount < 1)
{
    $response["error"] = true;
    echo json_encode($response);

}
else
{

    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['reasons'] = array_column($row, 'option', 'id');
    echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

**The current response look like this:**

```
{
  "error": false,
  "reasons": {
    "10": "Messy",
    "23": "Damaged",
    "48": "Other"
  }
}
```

**The response I am looking for:**

```
{
  "error": false,
  "reasons": [
    "1":{ "id": 10
          "reason": "Messy"
        }
    "2":{ "id": 23
          "reason": "Damaged"
        }
    "3":{ "id": 48
          "reason": "Other"
        }
  ]
}
```

How can this be achieved?'

**UPDATE:**
Calling: `$response['reasons'] = $row;`
Get the following result:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "reasons": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "reason": "Messy"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "reason": "Damaged"
    },
    {
      "id": 48,
      "reason": "Other"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the sequential numbers to appear before the each row result?

```
   "1":{
      "id": 10,
      "reason": "Messy"
    },
```

Comment: Don't call `array_column`, just use `$row`

Comment: Ok, this is very close to what I need, is it possible to get the sequential number to appear before each row result? These numbers should be a count of the results. Please see my updated post.

Comment: So you need the indexes to start from `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: Yes they must start from 1

Comment: You'll need to write your own loop that assigns indexes, since arrays start from 0 by default.

Comment: If it needed to start from 0 what would I need to add? I may just modify the front end to interpret the JSON from 0

Comment: you don't need to add anything, that's what happens by default.

Comment: it just doesn't show the indexes when they're sequential starting from 0. If you want `json_encode()` to create an object instead of an array in this case, use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag.

Comment: But in JavaScript, and array is just an object whose properties are integers starting from 0, so you shouldn't need to change the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the indexes to start from 1 instead of 0, you need to write a loop that assigns the keys.

```
$reasons = [];
foreach ($row as $i => $r) {
    $reasons[$i+1] = $r;
}
$response['reasons'] = $reasons;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I appreciate your help

Comment: Is there a way to replace the `"reasons": {` with a square bracket? `"reasons": [`

Comment: No. JSON arrays don't have keys, only objects do.

Comment: PHP has associative arrays, JSON and JavaScript don't.